# WebM audio issues in Firefox 4. Even tested in FF 7

Tags: html, firefox

I am facing a rather strange issue with Firefox. This is the webm file that I am trying to play:

http://www.filesonic.in/file/2825764155

This plays fine in Firefox but problem comes when I try to jump to a particular second using slider. It just stops playing the song. What can be the issue? I didn't face this problem in Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The file link didn't work for me. Since some issues stem from a particular file or server configuration, could you provide an updated link?